# How to catch uri calls with app selection from webview?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, uwp

I get the application selection popup when I'm loading some customer webcontent into my `webview`, I guess its calling and `uri` with an unknown protocol or something. I don't care about the contents, I just want to react before the popup appears.

[image: Popup for app selection]

I tried the following but I won't get called by

`webView.NavigationStarting += WebView_NavigationStarting;`

`webView.ScriptNotify += WebView_ScriptNotify;`

They are only called when expected, but not before the popup.

Is there another event I can subscribe to, so I can handle it and decide if it is necessary to show the popup or just flag it as handled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I get the application selection popup when I'm loading some customer webcontent into my webview.

The screenshot in your case is the window of `openwith.exe` system level app. It will be launched by unknown application `uri`(`Name:Parameter`) scheme. It will not invoke `NavigationStarting` and `ScriptNotify` event. For more you could refer to [Handle URI activation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/handle-uri-activation).

> Is there another event I can subscribe to, so I can handle it and decide if it is necessary to show the popup or just flag it as handled?

Currently, there is no such event  for detecting the popup.
For your requirement, you can filter the special uri scheme in the html page manually.

For more, you could refer to [Launch the default app for a URI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-default-app#uri-schemes). And create appropriate filter based on these uri scheme.

**Example**

```
function myFunction() {
    var url = "test:paramter"
    var arr = url.split(":");
    if (arr[0] == "test") {
        arr[0] = "";
    }
    var url = arr.join('');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!